# Why can't I iterate through list of lists this way?

Tags: python, list, loops

Sorry I'm fairly new to python, but I needed to take 6 individual lists and concatenate them such that they resemble a list of lists.

i.e. a1 from list A + b1 from list B + c1 from list C 
and  a2 from list A + b2.... etc

should become [[a1,b1,c1], [a2,b2,c2]...]

I tried this:

```
combList = [[0]*6]*len(lengthList)

for i in range(len(lengthList)):
    print i
    combList[i][0] = posList[i]
    combList[i][1] = widthList[i]
    combList[i][2] = heightList[i]
    combList[i][3] = areaList[i]
    combList[i][4] = perimList[i]
    combList[i][5] = lengthList[i]
    # i++
print combList
```

and then tried a variation where I appended instead:

```
    for i in range(len(lengthList)):
        print i
        combList[i][0].append(posList[i])
        combList[i][1].append(widthList[i])
        combList[i][2].append(heightList[i])
        combList[i][3].append(areaList[i])
        combList[i][4].append(perimList[i])
        combList[i][5].append(lengthList[i])
        # i++
    print combList
```

So I have two questions.

Why didn't either of those work, cus in my mind they should have. And I don't need to put i++ at the bottom right? For some reason it just wasn't working so I was just trouble shooting.

I ended up finding a solution, which is below, but I'd just like to understand what happened in the above two codes that failed so terribly.

```
for j in range(len(fNameList)):
            rows = [fNameList[j], widthList[j], heightList[j], areaList[j], perimeterList[j], lengthList[j]]
            print rows
            combList.append(rows)
        print combList
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue with at you did is that you are creating a list of 6 references to the same thing.

`[0]*6` will generate a list of 6 references to the same number (zero), and `[[0]*6]*len(lengthList)` will generate a list of references to the same `[0]*6` list.

I think the function you want is [`zip`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip):

```
A = ['a1','a2','a3']
B = ['b1','b2','b3']
C = ['c1','c2','c3']

print [x for x in zip(A,B,C)]
```

which gives:

```
[('a1', 'b1', 'c1'), ('a2', 'b2', 'c2'), ('a3', 'b3', 'c3')]
```

So in your case, this would work:

```
combList = [x for x in zip(fNameList, widthList, heightList, areaList, perimeterList, lengthList)]
```

Answer (score 3):

You are making a list of [*names*](http://python.net/~goodger/projects/pycon/2007/idiomatic/handout.html#other-languages-have-variables) all pointing at the same list of six zeros when you do:

```
combList = [[0]*6]*len(lengthList)
```

This is equivalent to doing this:

```
internal_list = [0] * 6
combList = [internal_list, internal_list, internal_list, internal_list, internal_list]
```

Instead, if you use `zip` you can get what you want in one pass:

```
zipped_list = zip(posList, widthList, heightList, areaList, perimList, lengthList)
```

Comment: I see! Thank you so much.. Never knew about python's "names" and I thought that zip was just to combine 2 lists to tuples, but now I know.

Answer (score 3):

`a = [0]*6` defines a list with 6 references, all those references point to the number `0`

`[a]*m` defines a list with `m` references, all pointing to `a`, in this case `[0]*6`.

The code in your final example works because it adds references to new objects, rather than modifying an existing one repeatedly.

Other people recommended you use [`zip`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip), and it is indeed the best solution, IMHO.

Answer (score 1):

You could do this with a comprehension across a zip, if the lists are all the same length

```
[list(tup) for tup in zip (l1, l2, l3...)]
```

Answer (score 1):

Depending on version of Python and how big your 3 lists are you should use either `zip` or `izip`.

[izip](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.izip) if you're running Python < 3 (you can use `zip` as well but if the lists are really big then a generator would be a whole heap faster and better for you).

[zip](http://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) if you're running Python >= 3

```
from itertools import izip

zipped_list = izip(a,b,c)

for item in zipped_list:
    print item
>> (1, 1, 1)
>> (2, 2, 2)
>> (3, 3, 3)
>> (4, 4, 4)
>> (5, 5, 5)
```

And just for a bit tutoring on how to write good clean looking Python:

Your loop that you've done `for i in range(len(lengthList)` could very easily be transformed to whats really Pythonic.

```
for item in lengthList:
```

Now you're thinking "what about my index, i can't access the index of the element".
Well Python has a fix for that too it's called [enumerate](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html?highlight=enumerate#enumerate) and you use it like so:

```
for index, item in enumerate(lengthlist):
```

So translating your code down to a more Pythonic syntax:

```
for index, element in enumerate(lengthList):
    combList[index][0].append(posList[index])
    combList[index][1].append(widthList[index])
    combList[index][2].append(heightList[index])
    combList[index][3].append(areaList[index])
    combList[index][4].append(perimList[index])
    combList[index][5].append(lengthList[index])
```